# ng-repeat performance - 1300 watchers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have something like 1300 watchers on ng-repeat, I have to reduce it.
the big problem is that lot of my things in my ng-repeat is 2-way binding because I need to change the list and insert new event to the list every x  time and handle functionality in the di

Plunker example of the lot of watchers and how the app works

https://plnkr.co/edit/rVIqaKbcnhAkvaeqcLA1?p=preview

My app is like the following:

get event Obj from server by polling every 3 seconds:

in my controller I get the data:

```
 vm.eventData  = Server.eventData;
```

index html:

```
<event-list
        settings-data ="vm.settings"
        event-data = "vm.eventData"
</event-list>
```

Event list directive:(handle when there is a new obj to the list and show the list in loading,  update by watchcollection when there is new event and update the scope.eventData

```
 scope.$watchCollection('eventData', function(newVal, oldVal){
}
```

event-data-directive.html

```
    <li id="listItem_{{event.id}}" ng-repeat="event in eventsData track by $index">
```

inside the li, I have a click directive to handle a click and show the event and on click, I need to update the view with the data from the eventsData array

I tried to add bindonce plugin but it is not help because its one way binding  and every action in my app affects the event list

So basically I have to reduce the watchers or change all my functionality , what do you think?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the list of elements is long (which I assume based on the many watchers), I suggest you look at something called virtual scroll/virtual ng-repeat.

What it basically does is it only renders the elements that are visible in the browser viewport. This effectively has the result of only adding the watchers for the content that is visible. Whenever the user scrolls more elements into view, the virtual scroll component seamlessly renders the new elements, and destroys the elements that moves out of view. Thus keeping the number of watcher somewhat constant, regardless of the number of elements in your list.

It can be tricky to get working on your own, so I suggest you look at modules such as [angular-vs-repeat](https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat) or, if you already use a framework that implements virtual scroll in certain components, enable it in those.

Comment: The list is just 30 elements and when a new arrived the old one deleted from the list by splice for example

Comment: Alright, then my answer wont do much. Could you share the code inside the `<li>`-element?

Comment: off course there is a lot of more code in the li with ng-if for example  but this code is the big watcher problem